# rawr jruby creating exe

Tags: rake, jruby, exe

I've a very simple Ruby script, which I've used rawr to package up into a `*.jar` file.  I can then run the `*.jar` file with `java -jar *.jar`.  I would like to make my program  into an executable so I did `rake rawr:bundle:exe`.  It says that it successfully created an executable and I can see the executable it created.

What I don't understand is, when I double click the executable (or attempt to run it in the command prompt), it doesn't really do anything; it is supposed to display 'hello' and wait for me to push enter (on STDOUT) but nothing really happens.  If I run the `*.jar` file, it displays 'hello'.  How am I supposed to run the executable?  I was expecting that when I double click the `*.exe`, that a command prompt window pop up displaying 'hello' and waiting for me to push enter...

Answer (score 0):

Since the program displays to STDOUT, and doesn't have a GUI component, I think you need to run this from the command prompt. Not sure what OS your on, since you said .exe, I'm assuming windows. so you just need to run it from the command prompt instead of by double-clicking on it.

so in the same folder where you are able to succesfully execute:

```
java -jar *.jar
```

just type:

```
myApplication.exe
```

Or, if your in another location on the machine you can type:

```
C:\full\path\to\myApplication.exe
```

Otherwise, the process is just going to run in the background with no way for you to see the results.